# Getting enchanted items and block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How would one get enchanted items (not tools)? Items like sugar and dirt. I want to summon enchanted sugar (I will hide enchantment using a flag; I just want it to "shine").

Comment: You know how to set the flags to hide enchantments but do not know how to get enchanted items?

Comment: I don't know. I tried normal "ench" tag but it just didn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it - you just need to leave ench field empty: `{ench:[]}`. It makes item glow like enchanted but i doesn't have any enchantments at all!

Answer (score 2):

As of 1.11, you'll need to have an enchantment inside the `ench` list for the glow to appear, rather than just an empty `ench` list:

```
/give @p dirt 1 0 {ench:[{}]}
```

A blank enchantment like this however will default to `id:0`, which is protection. If you don't want the item to appear to be enchanted with protection, you can set the `id` to `-1`:

```
/give @p dirt 1 0 {ench:[{id:-1}]}
```